# Copy Dolby E tracks without decoding

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm looking out for a way to put a dolby E wav into an mxf file with mono tracks.
I have two issues. Each time I tried to split Dolby E in mono it breaks Dolby E.
And when I try to copy the Dolby E in stereo it is decode.

How can I handle Dolby E without decoding and without breaking it ?

Here is the command I tried :

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -i dbe.wav -profile:v 0 -level:v 2 -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv422p -aspect 16:9 -intra_vlc 1 -b:v 50000000 -minrate 50000000 -maxrate 50000000 -bufsize 17825792 -rc_init_occupancy 17825792 -sc_threshold 1000000000 -bf 2 -non_linear_quant 1 -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 -colorspace bt709 -seq_disp_ext 1 -video_format component -color_range 1 -chroma_sample_location topleft -signal_standard 4 -dc 8 -qmin 3 -qmax 28 -strict 2 -g 12 -mpv_flags +strict_gop -field_order tt -top 1 -flags +ildct+ilme+cgop -alternate_scan 1 -vtag xd5c  -timecode 00:00:00:00 -vf "setfield=tff" -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -map 0:v -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -map 0:3 -map 0:4 -map_channel 1.0.0 -map_channel 1.0.1 -map_channel 1.0.0 -map_channel 1.0.1 -y -threads 0 output1.mxf
```

Thanks,

Comment: This is outside my field of expertise, but can't your video editor import the Dolby E directly?

Comment: What have you tried so far (show the command lines you are using) ?

Comment: I edited with my command line.

Comment: Basically I try to split my Dolby E from stereo track to two mono tracks in a mxf output.

Comment: Would be better to focus on the audio part in your command and leave the video with ```-c:v copy``` at the moment... Anyway... Dolby E is by design encoded in a PCM stereo stream that behaves like a container, so I'm not sure it makes sense at all to split it into 2 mono streams. I think I understand what you want to do, but this looks like dumping raw values rather than dealing with audio...

Comment: What I would try :
1) convert the DBE file into a raw PCM file (that is, raw sample without headers) ```ffmpeg -i dbe.wav -c:a copy dbe.pcm```, but I'm sure ffmpeg will accept to do that, and 
2) split the channels ```ffmpeg -f s16le -ar 48k -ac 2 -i dbe.pcm -filter_complex channelsplit output.wav

Comment: Yes, I did split my command in two step. I create the XDCAM mxf then I try to add the Dolby E tracks but either the Dolby E is decoding instead of copying or it doesn't work according to how I try to do it. A lot of broadcast mxf has Dolby E embedded in mono tracks. Actually I can copy Dolby E tracks from an mxf to another just fine but I haven't any solution when the source is external.

Comment: I think I could have find something that work. You give me some ideas thanks. Here what seems to work. ffmpeg -i input4tracks.mxf -f s24le -ac 2 -ar 48k -i dbe.wav -filter_complex "[1:0]pan=1c|c0=c0[left],[1:0]pan=1c|c0=c1[right]" -acodec pcm_s24le -ar 48k -c:v copy -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -map 0:3 -map 0:4 -map "[left]" -map "[right]" -filter_complex "[1:0]pan=1c|c0=c0[left2],[1:0]pan=1c|c0=c1[right2]" -map "[left2]" -map "[right2]" -y -threads 0 output8tracksWithDBE.mxf